# Padding integers with zeros in Helm value

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a need to construct Kubernetes objects with name containing three digits padded with leading zeros.

For example with an iteration, I am trying to create StatefulSets with names

```
"XXXX-001"
"XXXX-002"
...
```

I have tried

```
printf "%s has **%3d** dogs." .Name .NumberDogs.
```

but the %3d isn't padding this to 3 digits.

And I tried to look into Helm Template Function List, but could not find anything which can help my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printf` template function uses the [Go `fmt` package](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) internally, and its documentation has the rules for constructing the `%` strings.  `%3d` should request a string that is (at least) three characters wide, but the default padding is with spaces; you need to include a `0` modifier as well to get zero padding.

```
printf "%03d dogs" .NumberDogs
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for explaining! yes, when I tried %3d it was padding with spaces. And your answer works perfectly! Thank you!